# Will I be in the cheaters lobby after my ban lifts?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-online

I just got banned from GTA Online for 2 weeks and I wonder if I'll be in cheaters lobby after 2 weeks.

Also yes, it is my first time of getting banned.

[image: Banned]

Comment: Dear God, I hope you're joking about treating that straw poll as actual evidence.

Comment: @Studoku however, removed it. Let me make it a comment: Loads of people got banned so I don't think that It'll be that bad in cheater lobbies (http://strawpoll.me/4254902/r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some rockstar employees stated that we will be able to resume playing when the ban lifts. The meaning I get off this is we will not be in a cheater lobby.

> Hi there! Your ban will be lifted by May 16th. You will be able to **resume playing** once the ban is lifted. If you feel this was done in error, please submit a ticket request [here](http://rsg.ms/support) and we will assist you.

Taken from [here](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203880047-GTA-PC-Ban).